# Powershell - trapping cancel on input

Tags: powershell, prompt

I have a function that returns a selected value except when the prompt is closed.  The function is:

```
function Read-Choice {
#.Synopsis
#  Prompt the user for a choice, and return the (0-based) index of the selected item
#.Parameter Message
#  The question to ask
#.Parameter Choices
#  An array of strings representing the "menu" items, with optional ampersands (&) in them to mark (unique) characters to be used to select each item
#.Parameter DefaultChoice
#  The (0-based) index of the menu item to select by default (defaults to zero).
#.Parameter Title
#  An additional caption that can be displayed (usually above the Message) as part of the prompt
#.Example
#  Read-Choice "WEBPAGE BUILDER MENU"  "Create Webpage","View HTML code","Publish Webpage","Remove Webpage","E&xit"
PARAM([string]$message, [string[]]$choices, [int]$defaultChoice=0, [string]$Title=$null )
   if($choices[0].IndexOf('&') -lt 0) {
      $i = 0; 
      $choices = $choices | ForEach-Object {
         if($_ -notmatch '&.') { "&$i $_" } else { $_ }
         $i++
      }
   }
   $Host.UI.PromptForChoice( $Title, $message, [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]$choices, $defaultChoice )
}
```

I'm calling it as follows:

```
$SetDeletes = read-choice "Delete Files" "Recycle","Kill","E&xit" 0 $message
```

The user is prompted with a choice of 0 Recycle, 1 Kill or Exit.  If one of those three are selected and the user hits OK, it returns whatever value was selected (0,1 or 2).  However, if the prompt is closed, or if the user hits cancel, the script aborts with a message as follows:

> Exception calling "PromptForChoice" with "4" argument(s): "An error of
>   type "System.Management.Automation.Host .PromptingException" has
>   occurred."

How can the Cancel key on the prompt be trapped and handled?  If no selection is made, I want to default to the 0 value, - Recycle and to continue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro this on V3 which is nice for V3 users but in the V2 case have you tried putting a try/catch around the the PromptForChoice call:

```
try {
    $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $message, $choices, $defaultChoice)
}
catch [Management.Automation.Host.PromptingException] {
    $defaultChoice
}
```